# Clarify Elixir Syntax used in Phoenix Migration File (specifically the "create" function)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm very confused about this syntax:

```
create table(:topics) do
  add :title, :string
end
```

`create` is a function that takes argument `table()`, which is another function, correct me if i'm wrong?  But then is followed by a function body?

Could someone explain how this works?

Comment: Good question, I'm personally not sure how to best answer the question but here is where some of the sausage is being made https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/migration/runner.ex

Answer (score 1):

[`create/2`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/migration.ex#L307-L309) is a macro that takes two values. Just because you are calling it like

```
create table(...) do 
  ...
end
```

Doesn't ment you have to. [`table/2`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/migration.ex#L486-L494) is just a function. You could write the above statement as

```
table = table(:my_table)
create my_table do
  ...
end
```

You are not passing a function into the create macro, you are passing a value that just happens to come from a function into the create macro.

Answer (score 0):

`do ... end` is not necessarily a function body. It's generic syntax, which when used with a macro, passes the AST (abstract syntax tree) of its contents to the macro. Here's a demonstration:

```
defmodule A do
  defmacro a(args) do
    IO.inspect args
  end

  def main do
    a do
      1 + 2
    end
  end
end

A.main
```

Output:

```
[do: {:+, [line: 8], [1, 2]}]
```

So it's just the AST of the body of the block, passed as a keyword list with the key `do`.

`create` then is just a macro which accepts two arguments: the first is table, and the second is the `do ... end` block. The macro then transforms the block and executes it. You can see [the source code](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/bba34c5ba218537bf196630179e4934946ab94e0/lib/ecto/migration.ex#L307) of the function for more details.